# S3 uploader throwing exception while trying to upload huge files

Tags: ios, macos, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, nsexception

I was trying to upload a huge file (8GB) using Amazon sdk for MAC (though they dnt have an sdk for MAC, I have modified the IOS sdk source code by removing the UIKit references and recompiled for MAC). It's actually working for files, maybe upto 800MB ~ 1GB. But whenever I tried to upload a 8GB file, I am getting an exception. The exception says that "Internet connection is lost". Weird, I am having good internet connection (2Mbps upload speed :-/). I am using multipart upload api and uploading chunks of 5MB. When I get an exception, I am not giving up but I will retry the same chunk for at least 5 times and then give up. In between this retry I am sleeping for a few seconds. But the most amazing part is, once a chunk upload face an exception, it won't really work in retry. I don't understand it. Can any one help me out????

Thanks in advance!

Below am adding the code too!

```
        fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];

        S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest* initReq = [[S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithKey:requestDetails.md5 inBucket:requestDetails.bucket];
        initReq.contentType = requestDetails.contentType;

        S3MultipartUpload* upload = [amazonS3Client_ initiateMultipartUpload:initReq].multipartUpload;
        S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest* compReq = [[S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];


        compReq.contentType = requestDetails.contentType;

        NSData* data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:PART_SIZE];
        int part = 0;
        ...............................
        while([data length] > 0)
        {
                @try {
                    S3UploadPartRequest* upReq = [[S3UploadPartRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];
                    upReq.partNumber = part + 1;
                    upReq.contentLength = data.length;
                    upReq.data = data;
                    upReq.contentType = requestDetails.contentType;

                    response = [amazonS3Client_ uploadPart:upReq];
                    [compReq addPartWithPartNumber:(part + 1) withETag:response.etag];

                    offset += [data length];

                    [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
                    data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:PART_SIZE];
                    part++;
                    ........................
                }
                @catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
                    .............................

                    if([exception.message rangeOfString:@"expire"].location != NSNotFound)
                    {
                        // renew credentials code 
                        return [self multipartUpload:requestDetails withFilePath:filePath];
                    }

                }
            }
      [amazonS3Client_ completeMultipartUpload:compReq];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  While we haven't tested with files of that size I can't think of anything in the SDK that would be causing this.  Some things you might want to try and/or include in your question:

1. The latest versions of the AWS SDK for iOS include an option to disable exceptions from the SDK itself.  This might show whether the source of exception is in the SDK or something else.
2. You say you are retrying on exception, but are you re-using the request or creating a new one?  Including your code may help others offer suggestions.
3. When you get into this state, can you execute any other operations?  Are you sure that you haven't caused your network connection to reset in some way?

**Follow up**

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to reproduce the issue with the latest version of the AWS SDK for iOS over the past few days and haven't been successful.  I was able to successfully upload a 10GB file to Amazon S3 using multipart upload.

I wanted to summarize some findings and give some recommendations for next steps:

1. You should really update the SDK.  There have been a number of updates for the AWS SDK for iOS over the 6 months since you said you downloaded, some in relation to connection handling, that may help with this problem.
2. Your test for internet connectivity may not be testing the right thing.  You did not include the code for this, so it's unclear, but if all you're testing is that the local devices have link and can get to their gateway, that is not necessarily a valid indicator that there isn't a problem with your connection to Amazon S3.  The fact that you were getting timeouts (more on this later) is an indication that your computer was having problems *connecting* to Amazon S3.  There are a number of reasons this could happen including faulty network hardware or explicit traffic shaping by your ISP.
3. There's an inconsistency in the SDK with regards to timeout handling.  For all clients besides S3, the timeout is applied to the NSURLConnection object as well as processing the actual request.  For S3, it is only applied to processing of the request meaning that the NSURLConnection timeoutInverval property is unmodified.  The NSURLConnection timeoutInterval property is a timeout to *establish* the connection.  Once data is being sent or received, even if it is just a trickle, NSURLConnection will not timeout.  This means that if you are receiving timeout exceptions, your computer was unable to establish a connection to Amazon S3 for the default timeoutInterval (60s).  We'll review and patch the SDK as appropriate to address this inconsistency.
4. As I stated in my original answer, it would be good to confirm if you can make another request to Amazon S3 (like a list buckets/objects) as well as get to another external resource like google.com when you get into this failure state.  This would at least empower you to go your ISP and ask better questions about what is going on.

Hope this information helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have pasted the code above. You can go through it. And coming to your questions 1: I might be using an older version. I downloaded it 6 mnths back. 2: In every retry am creating a new request. You can see it in code. 3: I am pretty sure that I have connection, when I get exception. And one more point to note is, am getting another exception too for big files. It says 'Request time out', though I have set 'INT_MAX' as the time out value :-o

Comment: To be clear: is the exception from the upload part request or when your checking the internet connection?

Comment: @Advaith Sorry to ask for more information, but if you can include additional logging from the AmazonLogger that may also help diagnose the issue.  I agree it's odd that you would be getting timeouts with such a large value.  You are definitely exercising the SDK in a way that is outside our supported use case, but we'll see if we can help.

Comment: I am throwing the exception just to make sure that, if I the exception was due to lack of internet connection I don't want to retry. I debugged and it's not getting in. it's throwing from 'if (retryCount > 5)' condition. And that is why I told that am pretty sure that I am not loosing internet connection. TA :)

Comment: @Advaith Regarding the timeout errors: there's a bug in the S3 client setting timeouts larger than the default value, so if your request takes longer than 240s (I think the default is 60s on OS X) it will timeout regardless of what timeout value was set on the S3 client.  We'll fix that in the SDK.

Comment: @Advaith we released an update to the SDK last night that has some additional improvements.  You may want to consider updating to this version. http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/SDKs/iOS/7246485786863279

Comment: Hey Bob, one more help pls. I am facing one more issue with old sdk. I was trying to upload a 800 MB folder as 5 MB chunks. it went fine for some 125 parts. 126th part was put to upload and I never received a response back from server. Could this be an issue with your sdk? if YES, is it resolved in latest sdk?

Comment: @Advaith All I can say is that I don't see that issue with the latest version of the SDK.  If you continue to encounter the problem with the latest version, let me know and we can investigate.

Comment: thanks again. I will update to new sdk and let you know the results.

Comment: hey Bob, I updated the sdk. But still I am getting the hang issue which I suspect might be a timeout issue. And I am getting it when I have a connection but it's too slow. Actually I am using asynchronous upload and some strange things are happening. I have implemented some delegate methods to know the status of upload. And the only thing I am doing is an upload process. But I don't know why I am getting a callback to "-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data" method sometimes.

Comment: @Advaith You may want to tune the timeout values on the clients.  If you are still having problems, I encourage you to post a new question with your code and any tests you've run.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. What you have said is correct. I was assuming that time out value was in milliseconds, but actually in new sdk it was in seconds and that was the issue. thanks for your help :)